# GET request ignores my parameters in python request

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send a GET request to an API endpoint with some parameters, but the parameters are ignored by the endpoint.

I have tried to define p in many ways, without succes.
I get the result back as if no parameters were added to the request.

How is this done? I expect, that it has to go into the URL somehow.

API docs says that a query Parameter "fields" can be added, and that it must contain a list of fields to be returned:

fields

string Nullable

Default: "Guid,ContactName,Date,Description"

A comma separated list of fields to include in the response. Possible values are: Number, Guid, ExternalReference, ContactName, ContactGuid, Date, PaymentDate, Description, Currency, Status, MailOutStatus, TotalExclVatInDkk, TotalInclVatInDkk, TotalExclVat, TotalInclVat, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt and DeletedAt. If null, defaults to Guid,ContactName,Date,Description. Notice that it's not case sensitive, the property name will be returned the way you request it.

This is my code

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.dinero.dk/v1/257403/invoices'
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }
p = {'fields' :"Number, Guid, ContactName, Date, Status"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=p)
print (response.text)
```

Comment: I think this is happening because you're including spaces in your `p['fields']` value. try using:
`p = {'fields': "Number,Guid,ContactName,Date,Status"}`

Comment: also, can you include the output of your print call?

Comment: Thanks! That's was it. Please leave an answer.

Comment: awesome, added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because you're including spaces in your `p['fields']` value. try using:

```
p = {'fields': "Number,Guid,ContactName,Date,Status"}
```